# Multiple statements in Ternary Operator

Tags: php

I want to convert a small condition in php to ternary operator.

```
if($i==2) {
    $third="third";
    $i=0;
} else {
    $third="";
}
```

How to Translate this to ternary operator?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to convert a perfectly valid and readable condition to a ternary operator? (`$third = $i==2 ? $i=0, "third" : ""` should work, though totally unreadable)

Comment: You can't convert this to ternary operator code.

Comment: @knittl Doesn't work, Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ: It's probably getting more votes for the first sentence.  There's no good reason to do this.

Answer (score 22):

You can use like this format:

```
$i==2 ? ($third = "third" AND $i = 0) : ($third="");
```

Comment: Awesome stuff that is

Comment: It is strange but in my case its working when i have syntax like this:
$i==2 ? ($third = "third" . $i = 0) : ($third="");

Answer (score 3):

Because i'm bored:

```
list($i, $third) = array(($not2 = ($i != 2)) * $i, ($not2) ? '' : 'third');
```

or

```
list($i, $third) = ($i == 2) ? array(0, 'third') : array($i, '');
```

or maybe

```
$third = ($i == 2 ? "third" : '') and $i = 0;
```

or

```
$i *= !($third = ($i == 2) ? 'third' : '');
```

But don't do this in real life.  Seriously.  You have a perfectly readable `if`; there's no good reason to turn it into a mess like this.